# My Bitcoin transaction hasn't confirmed in over 57 Hours. What can I do to speed it up?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

Here is the transaction 5f15aae40fad7328f8ea2986595c105d423d429e3513d8bcbb1b93934ff0c0f7

Answer (score 0):

[Your transaction](https://blockchain.info/tx/5f15aae40fad7328f8ea2986595c105d423d429e3513d8bcbb1b93934ff0c0f7) paid a fee of 101 satoshis per byte. With the [current fee market](https://bitcoinfees.earn.com/), your transaction should be confirmed in about 17 hours. You could try using a [transaction accelerator](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_accelerator) but the network is pretty jammed right now.

Comment: Cheers for the answer David! do you know any way to change the fee when sending it? My exchange set the fee really low and really screwed me over here.

Comment: The sender could have specified any fee they wanted to. Unfortunately, it's not particularly easy to raise the fee on a transaction. It might not be their fault, they may have submitted the transaction just before fees shot up. But most exchanges are using around three times that fee right now.

Comment: Yeah I didn't consider that. Thanks for all the help David.